# Difference between Web SQL and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

After a long search still am not able to find a difference between Web SQL and SQLite.

- Are both HTML5 based?
- Web SQL has a storage limit whereas with SQLite there is no storage limit?
- Is an external plugin required for SQLite in phonegap? As [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) states that following code will create a SQLite database:

  `var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);`

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could make sense when you use SQLite on client side, it will be implemented using Web SQL as the specification for Web SQL says:

> This specification introduces a set of APIs to manipulate client-side databases using SQL.

so the web sql provides a bunch of API's to manipulate relational databases on the front end, however i haven't find any relational databases on the client side other than sqlite(haven't found any widely used) and this piece from the specification also gives some hint:

> This document was on the W3C Recommendation track but specification work has stopped. The specification reached an impasse: all interested implementors have used the same SQL backend (Sqlite)